# Struts2 xml validation is not working

Tags: java, forms, struts2, tags

Here is my Register-validation.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>

    <validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="fieldname">userBean.username</param>
        <message>User name is required.</message>
    </validator>

    <validator type="required">
        <param name="fieldname">profileBean.Age</param>
        <message>Age is required.</message>
    </validator>

</validators>
```

Here is my form.

```
<s:form action="register">

        <label>UserName</label>
        <s:textfield cssClass="formfield" name="userBean.username"
            label="User Name" />
        <br />
        <label>Password</label>
        <s:password cssClass="formfield" name="userBean.password"
            label="Password" />
        <br />
        <label>First Name</label>
        <s:textfield cssClass="formfield" name="profileBean.firstName"
            label="First Name" />
        <br />
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <s:textfield cssClass="formfield" name="profileBean.lastName"
            label="Last Name" />
        <br />
        <label>Age</label>
        <s:textfield cssClass="formfield" name="profileBean.age" label="Age" />
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
```

Even though I not enter a value for username and age the form still keeps going in the success page. why is it not working?

**EDIT**

```
struts.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />

    <package name="basicstruts2" namespace="/Welcome" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="HelloWorld" class="actions.HelloWorldAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="Registration" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="register" class="actions.Register"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/thankyou.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Profile Bean

```
package model;

public class Profile {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

and User Bean

```
package model;

public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int accountType;//Admin  - 0; User - 1;
    private Profile profile;

    public User(){
        accountType = 1;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public int getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }
    public void setAccountType(int accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }
    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }


}
```

Register Action

```
public class Register extends ActionSupport  implements ServletRequestAware{

    public String execute(){

        userBean.setProfile(getProfileBean());
        return "success";
    }

    private User userBean;
    private Profile profileBean;
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public User getUserBean() {
        return userBean;
    }

    public void setUserBean(User userBean) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }

    public Profile getProfileBean() {
        return profileBean;
    }

    public void setProfileBean(Profile profileBean) {
        this.profileBean = profileBean;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
        return this.request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your bean too. Age is written wrong (Age instead of age)

Comment: even though I did change it to age it is still not working.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you getting any exceptions while submitting the form?  2. Are you running the application behind the firewall?

Comment: @ViralPatel actually I do, but it is just a warning. here's the warning 
 WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'register' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried to run your code. your error is that you need to provide a result named `input`.will look for this result if validation fails.

```
<package name="Registration" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="register" class="actions.Register"
            method="execute">
          <result name ="input">erropage.jsp</result>  
          <result name="success">/thankyou.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Comment: The Egg of Columbus... any clue on why it did not raise the error message "No result defined for Action and result Input" ???

Answer (score 2):

In your Register-validation.xml file can you change the dtd definition from:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

So that your Register-validation.xml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>

    <validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="fieldname">userBean.username</param>
        <message>User name is required.</message>
    </validator>

    <validator type="required">
        <param name="fieldname">profileBean.Age</param>
        <message>Age is required.</message>
    </validator>

</validators>
```

Comment: Is your `Register-validation.xml` present in same package as of  `Register.java`?

Answer (score 1):

I use XML Validation like this (different syntax):

```
  <validators>
      <field name="profileBean.age">
          <field-validator type="required">
              <message><![CDATA[ Age is required ]]></message>
          </field-validator>
      </field>

      <field name="userBean.username">
          <field-validator type="requiredstring">
              <message><![CDATA[ Username is required ]]></message>
          </field-validator>
      </field>
  </validators>
```

Try it.

P.S: I've written something about this **[here](http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/06/struts-2-struts-2-xml-validation.html)**.

EDIT:

Try changing this

```
<s:form action="register">
```

to this

```
<s:form action="/register">
```

(or eventually to `<s:form action="register" namespace="/">`)

including the namespace. The error you reported in comments to AleksandrM's answer is telling you that namespaces are messed up... (and thinking about it, you are on "/Welcome", looking up for an action located in "/" without specifying a namespace... this could fire some lookup mechanism that bypass the validation file and just find the Action)

I hope is this, I've run out of ideas :)

Comment: Are you sure you are using ValidationInterceptor ? Post profileBean and userBean and struts config please. This is tested, the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I am not using ValidationInterceptor, where would I place it?

Comment: All your validations are executed by ValidationInterceptor. It is part of the Default Interceptors Stack, so IF you haven't touched anything, you are using it. If you changed your stack (let's say you added custom interceptors etc), you have to check that it is included

Comment: I haven't touched anything to it. I already updated my question please check it

Comment: Yeah, it seems fine... is your Register-validation.xml in the same package of the Register.java Action ?

Comment: (and it is copied to the class package too ? :)

Comment: I just checked it and it is also in there.

Comment: open the generated war and check inside it

Comment: The only missing piece is the Action... can you post it too ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21278/discussion-between-andrea-ligios-and-user962206)

Answer (score 0):

You are using non-field validator and parameter for field name must be `fieldName` instead of `fieldname`. BTW it is preferable to use field validator syntax.

```
<field name="userBean.username">
  <field-validator type="requiredstring">
    <message>User name is required.</message>
  </field-validator>
</field>
```

Comment: I already changed the fieldname to filedName but it still does nothing

Comment: Hmm.. try to put `<s:fielderror/>` tag inside your JSP. See if it shows something.

Comment: Still not working. although i my console this showed up
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'register.action' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.

Comment: Correct all mistakes that you have in your configuration validation, check that your action/method is being called and use `<s:fielderror/>` tag to see if there are any field errors in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I resolved it putting actionClass-validation.xml under the same folder where my actionClass.java was residing.